# ExtJS Split button in grid cell

Tags: extjs, datagrid, extjs3, split-button

I want to use split button in grid cell. I define renderer for cell, but I can't put extjs component in grid cell. Can anyone help?

Split button: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/menu/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put components in grid cells, which is an odd limitation.

Check out http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column , he has built an extension that overcomes this.